# Can you sort this ArrayList in two different ways writing your own Comparator?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of object called Course and I'm trying to sort it in 2 ways, by courseID and courseStartTime.

Edit:  to clarify I mean I want to sort it by courseID at some point in time, and at another time later sort it by courseStartTime.

```
class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
    private int courseID;
    private String courseBeginTime;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Course course) {
        //what to return?
    }
```

If I wrote 2 of my own comparators, one to compare `courseID` and the other for `courseStarTime`, then the `compareTo()` method in the class isn't used and I don't know what to return.

If I want to use the `compareTo()` method, I'm not sure how to write it so I can compare `courseID` and `courseStartTime`.

Comment: "and I don't know what to return" - well, the result of comparing whichever attribute that implementation is interested in. It's not really clear what your question is...

Comment: Not sure I am following, do you want two different orderings? Or you have a primary and secondary order (i.e. use secondary only if the primary is identical)?

Comment: Write two [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Don't bother making your class Comparable at all; just use whichever Comparator is appropriate whenever you want to sort.

Comment: Short answer: yes you can. However you will require two lists to store the results, in addition to your original list. `Collections.sort()` modifies the list in place.

Comment: Do you want to order primarily by one attribute, say courseID, and have courses with equal IDs ordered by the other attribute?

Comment: To clarify I want 2 different ordering. 1 to sort by courseID, another to sort by courseBeginTime. If I wrote two Comparators, the compareTo method isn't even used. So what would I write in my compareTo method in the case where I'm going to write two Comparators and the compareTo method won't be used?

Comment: *Don't* write a compareTo method.

Comment: If you are using Comparator, the method you have to implement is compare() and not compareTo().

Comment: So if I am using my own Comparator, does that mean I didn't need to implement Comparable in my Course class and then I just need to implement compare() in the Comparators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement two different comparators.

```
public class CourseComparatorById implements Comparator<Course> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Course o1, Course o2) {
        // for example - sort ascending by ID
        return o1.getId() - o2.getId();
    }
}

public class CourseComparatorByStartTime implements Comparator<Course> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Course o1, Course o2) {
        // for example - sort ascending by start time
        return o1.getStartTime() - o2.getStartTime();
    }
}
```

And then use them to sort the array.

```
List<Course> courses = ...

Collections.sort(courses, new CourseComparatorById());
// now it's sorted by ID

Collections.sort(courses, new CourseComparatorByStartTime());
// now it's sorted by start time
```

Comment: So in this case class Course no longer needs to implements Comparable<Course>, correct?

Comment: It does not. If you want to have an entity comparable in two separate ways, then this is AFAIK your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the Java 8 Lambda way:

```
// this sorts by courseID
courseList.sort((c1, c2) -> Integer.valueOf(c1.courseID).compareTo(c2.courseID));

// this sorts by String courseBeginTime
courseList.sort((c1, c2) -> c1.courseBeginTime.compareTo(c2.courseBeginTime));
```

Note that is Java 8 you don't have to use `Collections.sort`, because the new `List` interface also provides a `sort` method

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this is being used for an online registration web app ...
you will probably be fetching the data source from a RDB ...  It wouldnt be wise to put ALL courses in one list (one entity) and save that. I would create an object (containing courseID and courseBeginTime) for EVERY course and save them all. Then when querying, add hints to sort your entities based on whatever root parameters you have in them (like courseID or courseBeginTime), ending with a List containing objects sorted the way you want :) :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should do something like this

```
public class Course implements Comparator<Course> {

    private int compareTime(int lhsTime, int rhsTime) {
        if (lhsTime > rhsTime) {
            return 1;
        } else if (lhsTime == rhsTime) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public int compare(Course lhs, Course rhs) {
        if (lhs.id > rhs.id) {
            return 1;
              //Get the time object from course obj and pass to compaerTime
        } else if (lhs.courseStarTime == rhs.courseStarTime) {
            return compareTime(lhs, rhs);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how would I call it then if I need it sorted by courseID vs courseStartTime?

Comment: You can call like this Collections.sort(unSortedList, new CourseCompare())